# scrape table from a webpage using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I hope to get the table contents of [this website](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/fees-and-charges/current-visa-pricing). However, the webpage's design is very special and my code below is only able to get the table in the first page:

I know since there are only three pages I can just copy manually, however I still hope to write a script that can automate the entire process.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url) 
time.sleep(5)   
html_str = driver.page_source 
soup = bs(html_str, "html.parser")
soup.find("table")
```

Here is the pagnitor part from `soup`, I have no experience in web-development and do not understand what actually happens after we click Next.

```
<ha-paginator data-translation-block="false" data-translation-id="1442"><!-- --><nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="text-center" data-translation-block="false" data-translation-id="1443">
<ul class="pagination" data-translation-block="false" data-translation-id="1444">
<!-- -->
<!-- --><li class="active" data-translation-block="false" data-translation-id="1445">
<!-- --><a data-translated="false" data-translation-checksum="57ad7d2ec0e248914c2b0ae7efc17011d1435f99d807e43b172697027ffe46ce500c3ff64f5162eaa059c11a23fa5d8c442ab67bd219d74311601bed517cf477" href="#"> 1
        <!-- --><span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
</li><li data-translation-block="false" data-translation-id="1446">
<!-- --><a data-translated="false" data-translation-checksum="7eece0387dc3c6876397df60e2d7dbe0e2c94ecdc42d7e50d5208a4c84885caa703c487d86900ac97f10ad493893db85144cf7889d8ac8fd008dfd4c8f0e98df" href="#"> 2
        <!-- -->
</a>
</li><li data-translation-block="false" data-translation-id="1447">
<!-- --><a data-translated="false" data-translation-checksum="aa08ec665075172d835562b332e78832e7f9d3b7f3df47d5a32b8f3a1682daaed49831faf19eeaca164d8e94e3449ade2a83d83dfaa83878c832f644fea11f95" href="#"> 3
        <!-- -->
</a>
</li><!-- --><li data-translated="false" data-translation-block="true" data-translation-checksum="7d03f54e74b11d46eacd33365a0aa16a3ba2857949c7f795c2d9c07b5689fbc4230dc22c45af2303eba21a7d8016f197d9b474d4149db6d0df059ce00416e192" data-translation-id="1448">
<a href="#">
          Next
        </a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<!-- --></ha-paginator>
<hr class="big" data-translation-block="true" data-translation-id="1449"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</ha-table-search>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL via JavaScript, so you can get data directly from there:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/_layouts/15/api/data.aspx/GetPriceList"

data = requests.post(url, json={"category": "Visa", "onshore": "All"}).json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data["d"]["data"])

df.pop("note")
print(df.head(5))
```

Prints:

```
  visaSubclassCode                                           visaSubclassText streamCode streamText onShore    basePrice  over18Price under18Price nonInternetPrice subsequentPrice
0              100  Partner (Provisional and Migrant) visa (subclass 309/100)                            No  AUD8,850.00  AUD4,430.00  AUD2,215.00              N/A             N/A
1              101                                  Child visa (subclass 101)                            No  AUD3,055.00  AUD1,530.00    AUD765.00              N/A             N/A
2              102                               Adoption visa (subclass 102)                            No  AUD3,055.00  AUD1,530.00    AUD765.00              N/A             N/A
3              117                        Orphan Relative visa (subclass 117)                            No  AUD1,870.00    AUD935.00    AUD470.00              N/A             N/A
4              124                   Distinguished Talent visa (subclass 124)                            No  AUD4,110.00  AUD2,055.00  AUD1,030.00              N/A             N/A
```